# Symfony 4 login access: no data persistence

Tags: php, symfony

I need to make a login form to allow the identified visitor to have access to the admin panel.

I have a form to login as admin. There is a redirection to this login form, whenever someone wants to access the path `/admin*`.

However, I have a problem with data persistence and it seems that I am never logged in.

#### My security.yaml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        in_database:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: true

            provider: in_database
            pattern: /admin*

            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                check_path: security_login

            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: home

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/(connexion)$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

#### My MainController :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/connexion", name="security_login")
 */
 public function login() {
     return $this->render('admin/login.html.twig');
 }
```

#### My HTML form:

```
    <form action="{{ path('security_login') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse mail" required name="_username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" required name="_password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Connexion</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

#### PHP

In my User Entity, which allows me to create only Admin Users identified by their email, I have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields={"email"},
 *  message="L'email que vous avez indiqué est déjà utilisé !"
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min="8", minMessage="Votre mot de passe doit faire au minimum {{limit}} caractères")
     */
    private $password;

     /**
     * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="password", message="Vous n'avez pas tapé le même mot de passe")
     */
    public $confirm_password;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {}

    public function getSalt() {}

    public function getRoles() {
  return ['ROLE_ADMIN'];
    }
```

#### Question

Why aren't the data persistent after the login form is submitted?
What should I add/modify to solve my problem and obtain an access to the admin panel (with redirection to it) after completing the form?

Comment: So why you build entire authentication process by yourself having no knowledge about Symfony whatsoever? Did you follow the official [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path used for your login route (i.e. `/connexion`) is not behind the firewall that you try to authenticate your user for. The easiest solution is to drop the `pattern` option for your `main` firewall as you do not really have the need for more than one firewall and `main` can just handle all requests (except the ones for the development tools which are excluded by the `dev` firewall).

Answer (score 0):

The data is not persisted because you don't persist it anywhere. You only render the form in the controller but there is no code responsible for saving the data in the database.

IMO First of all you need to build the form. You should create separate class (e.g UserType) responsible for rendering the fields in the form. [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/forms.html#creating-a-simple-form) you can read about building the forms and at the bottom you can see how to create a form type class that I mentioned above.

Second of all you should use for example EntityManager to persist and flush the user data into the database. Now you don't have code responsible for that. [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/doctrine/registration_form.html) you can read about creating a simple registration form in your Symfony app.

Example of controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/connexion", name="security_login")
 */
 public function login() 
{
    $user = $this->get('user_factory')->create();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
       $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($user);
       $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

       $this->addFlash(FlashType::SUCCESS, 'Account was created');

       return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/login.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: 'Account was created' inside a Login form ? really ? Also, this is not the way to handle logins in Symfony... not even remotely close.